# Heroku Free plan workers

Tags: heroku, sidekiq, worker

With the new June 2015 Heroku free plan, how does a sidekiq worker behave when a scheduled job is set to run while it's sleeping?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

Comment: Doesn't this belong on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Funny, as a [sf] moderator I was thinking it belonged on [so]. Wherever it belongs, it shouldn't be in both places!